# Perl OpenOffice::OODoc Modifying header/footer style text

Tags: perl, openoffice.org

I am trying to figure out how to change text in a footer of an ODT file. The footer is kept in the styles.xml, however I can't seem to access it using selectElementsByContent or any other method:

```
my $a = odfContainer('test.odt');
my $styles = odfDocument(container => $a, part => 'styles');

foreach my $element ($styles->selectElementsByContent('mytest'))
{
   #never runs...

}
```

The styles.xml in the odt is like:

```
<office:document-styles>
    <office:master-styles>
        <style:master-page>
            <style:footer>
                <text:p test:style-name="P49">
                    mytest
                </text:p>
            </style:footer>
        </style:master-page>
    </office:master-styles>
</office:document-styles>
```

What is the right way to change the text:p contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to use odfXPath to loop through:

```
my $ss = odfXPath(file => 'myfile.odt' , part => 'styles');
my $p =0;
while (my $p = $ss->getElement('//text:p',$p))
{
if ($ss->getText($para) eq 'mytest') { $ss->setText($p,'foobar');}
$p++;
}
$ss->save('mynewfile.odt');
```